# XCharter, XeLaTeX, and getting a pointy oldstyle numeral one

Tags: xetex, oldstylenums, xcharter

I am using the `XCharter` OTF font with XeLaTeX and I want a pointy oldstyle numeral 1, whereas what I get with my MWE below is something that looks like I.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Numbers=OldStyle]{XCharter}
\begin{document}
This is the oldstyle numeral 1.

This is the lining numeral $1$.

But how do I get the oldstyle version that looks like a reduced lining numeral in XeLaTeX?
\end{document}
```

There is a [similar question here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/436119/how-to-get-alternate-1-using-xcharter-with-luatex) but I do not use Lua and would like to know how to invoke the equivalent of `\useosf`in the  `XCharter` package, but for XeLaTeX.

Comment: The font contains a glyph named `one.Alt.oldstyle`, but it is not available as a stylistic set.

Answer (score 3):

With some help from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/255327/87678), you can access the glyph directly using:

```
\XeTeXglyph\the\XeTeXglyphindex "one.Alt.oldstyle"\relax
```

The glyph index was found using:

```
otfinfo -g XCharter-Roman.otf | grep one
```

## MWE

**Edit**: Don't make 1 active as it can easily cause problems. See comments from @UlrikeFischer below

**Edit 2**: Support `enumerate` environment with the `enumitem` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Numbers=OldStyle, Mapping=onealtoldstyle]{XCharter}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \l__chandra_counter_tl
\cs_new:Nn \__chandra_one_alt_oldstyle:
  {
    \XeTeXglyph\XeTeXglyphindex "one.Alt.oldstyle"\relax
  }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__chandra_alt_oldstyle:n
  {
    \tl_set:Nn \l__chandra_counter_tl {#1}
    \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l__chandra_counter_tl { 1 }
      { \__chandra_one_alt_oldstyle: }
    \tl_use:N \l__chandra_counter_tl
  }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__chandra_alt_oldstyle:n { x }
\NewDocumentCommand{\OldStyleArabic}{m}
  {
    \__chandra_alt_oldstyle:x {#1}
  }
\NewDocumentCommand{\OneAltOldstyle}{}
  {
    \__chandra_one_alt_oldstyle:
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\setlist[enumerate]{label=\OldStyleArabic{\arabic*}}
\begin{document}
This is the oldstyle numeral \OneAltOldstyle.

\begin{enumerate}
  \item Foo
  \item Bar
  \item Baz
\end{enumerate}

This is the lining numeral $1$.

This is \verb|tikz|: \tikz \draw (1, 1) -- (0, 1);
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE output]

Comment: You don't really suggest to make 1 active don't you?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, what should be done instead?

Comment: Well not this, try e.g. `\tikz\draw(1,1)--(0,1);` to get an idea about the problem with your approach. Btw: you don't need the \the, `\XeTeXglyph\XeTeXglyphindex "one.Alt.oldstyle"\relax` works.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, that was just copied from your answer ;). So is the best option for the OP just to use a macro?

Comment: Uff the \the not the active 1 is from my answer - you gave quite a shock ;-). Probably only a macro will work, the only other alternative I can think of with xelatex would be to try to create a teckit mapping, but I don't know if it could access the alternative glyph.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer OK, thanks! A TECkit mapping might be above my pay grade. I'll modify my answer. But maybe I will try and learn.

Comment: Could I use this solution in an `enumerate` list with arabic numerals? If so, how? Alternatively, is there a way to define the alternative one as the glyph to be used in a package like `enumitem`?

Comment: @chandra good question! I'll think some more

Comment: @chandra, I had a go at supporting the `enumitem` package using some `expl3` code.

Comment: @David Purton: Thank you for that "heroic" code, which works, but is beyond me. I also just realized that I had left out section and page numbers: the tedium multiplies trying to fix these. I have instead written to the package author who has told me that access to the pointy one in XeLaTeX will be available on the next update to `xcharter`.

Comment: @chandra, that is a much better solution

Answer (score 1):

Now that the package is updated it is possible to achieve this without heroic code by copying code from the very last page of the XCharter documentation. The MWE then becomes

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[CharacterVariant={1:0}, Numbers=OldStyle]{XCharter}
\begin{document}
This is the oldstyle numeral 1.

This is the lining numeral $1$.
\end{document}
```